# Excel chacnge the content of the field such as 3.03637285080476E+38 to be 3.03637E+38

Tags: excel

I have a sheet like the following.

```
Column 1
3.03637285080476E+38
3.03637285080476E+38
3.03637285080476E+38
3.03637285080476E+38
```

Excel sheet change the content to be

```
Column 1
3.03637E+38
3.03637E+38
3.03637E+38
3.03637E+38
```

I have tried to change the column type to be Text then I double click on each cell to solve the issue. 
Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1):

## Are the values numbers?

Find out with the `IsNumber` function.

For example, if your value is in cell `A1`, then in a *different* cell enter:

```
=IsNumber(A1)
```

- If it returns `TRUE` then the value is **numeric**.
- If it returns `FALSE` then the value is **text**.

---

### If the value is *numeric*:

Select the cell or range with the values and use the [image: increase] <sup>`Increase Decimals`</sup> and [image: decrease] <sup>`Decrease Decimals`</sup> buttons on the toolbar as required.

Alternatively, right-click the cell, choose `Format Cells`, and under the `Number` tab, choose `Scientific` (if it's not already selected) and change the decimal places as needed.

[image: format cells dialog]

---

### If the value is *text*:

Use a formula to change the value as required.

For example, if the value is in cell `A1`, you could use this formula in a *different* cell:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)+5)&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("E",A1)+1)
```

This would turn this text:

```
3.03637285080476E+38
```

into this:

```
3.03637E+38
```

Change the "`5`" to vary the number of decimal places shown.

---

### *"All together now"...*

You can even combine the above into one formula that will work on text *or* numbers (with the addition of an `IF` function and the `ROUND` function):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),ROUND(A1,5+4),LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)+5)&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("E",A1)+1))
```

Change both `5`s if you require decimal places other than "5".

---

*Scientific Notation* vs *Standard Notation*
If you would prefer to show a *regular* number (called *Decimal Notation* or  *Standard Notation*) number instead of the Scientific Notation, then you can:

1. Highlight the cells
2. Right-Click the cell(s) and click `Format Cells`
3. Under the `Number` tab, choose `Number`
4. Choose the desired number of decimal places

I assume you realize this already, but in case anyone's wondering:

The **Scientific** format displays a number in exponential notation,
replacing part of the number with E+n, where E (which stands for Exponent) multiplies the preceding number by **10 to the *n<sup>th</sup>* power**. 
For example, a 2-decimal Scientific format displays 12345678901 as 1.23E+10, which is 1.23 times 10 to the 10th power.

Therefore:

> **`3.0363E+08`**
>
> *is equivalent to:*
>
> **3.0363 × 10<sup>8</sup>**
>
> *which is the same as:*
>
> **3.0363 × 100000000**
>
> *which is the same as:*
>
> **`303630000`**

If the sign is a `-` instead of a `+`, then it is a *negative* exponent:

> **`3.0363E-08`**
>
> *is equivalent to:*
>
> **3.0363 × 10<sup>-8</sup>**
>
> *which is the same as:*
>
> **3.0363 × 0.000000001**
>
> *which is the same as:*
>
> **`0.000000030363`**

---

### More information:

- Office.com : [Display numbers in scientific (exponential) notation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-numbers-in-scientific-exponential-notation-f85a96c0-18a1-4249-81c3-e934cd2aae25?CorrelationId=fc894d17-ebf1-4f53-b0c8-5c14de953631&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HP001216511)
- Wikipedia: [Scientific Notation: Converting Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Converting_numbers)
- Math is Fun: [Scientific Notation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/scientific-notation.html)

Answer (score 0):

No need to change type of cell. Increase the number of digits to be shown. You have a button that looks like:

```
+-------+
|  <-0  |
|  .00  |
+-------+
```

Simply click on it.

Comment: Nothing change.

Comment: Did you set the focus on the cell in question (i.e. clicked on it)?

Comment: Suggestion: Enter into any cell the following formula: `=1/3`. Then, and while the focus is in the cell hosting this formula, play with the button I suggested and its opposite. You will see how the number of digits after the `.` changes.